# Why aren't my rectangles showing on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Trying out a simple game implementation

```
 public class PlayerSprite extends Rectangle {
private String name;
private int playerID;
final int TILE = 32;
final int SIZE = 4;

public PlayerSprite(PlayerCharacter player, int id, Paint color) {
    super(4, 4, color); //Currently a player takes up 4 points
    this.name = player.getName();
    this.playerID = id;

}
public int getPlayerSize() {
    return SIZE;
}
}
```

My playerSprites are just rectangles that currently aren't showing. The PlayerSprite constructor is called from an object called LocationHome that extends Region.

```
    public class LocationHome extends Region {
Image homeBGimage;
int lheight, lwidth;


public void LocationHome(Location location) {
    this.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(" + "'images/blackgrid.jpeg'" + ");" + "-fx-background-size: cover;");
    lheight = location.getLocationHeight(); //Location method call
    lwidth = location.getLocationWidth(); //Location method call
    this.setPrefSize(lheight, lwidth);
}

public void placePlayer(PlayerCharacter player) {
    //Create a PlayerSprite and position it as wanted
    Image img = new Image("images/blackgrid.jpeg");
    PlayerSprite playerSprite = new PlayerSprite(player, player.getID(), Color.AQUA);
    this.layoutInArea(playerSprite, player.getPosition().getUL().getX(), player.getPosition().getUL().getY(), playerSprite.getPlayerSize(), playerSprite.getPlayerSize(), 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.BASELINE);
    this.getChildren().addAll(playerSprite);
}
}
```

And then, for my main JavaFX application...

```
     Group rootPane = new Group();
     World guiWorld = new WorldImpl(); //This is my game model
     BorderPane locationPane = new BorderPane(); //locationPane designated for rendering a Location
     guiCharacters = new HashMap<>();
     int id=0;
     for(PlayerCharacter each : guiWorld.getCharacters()) {
        guiCharacters.put(id, each);
        gridLocation.placePlayer(each);
        id++;
     }
    locationPane.getChildren().addAll(gridLocation);
    rootPane.getChildren().add(locationPane);
     currScene = new Scene( rootPane, 1024, 1024 ); //Passing the rootPane/group to currScene
    stage.setScene(currScene); //Make currScene contents visible
    stage.setTitle("Spoon Game");
    stage.show();
```

Comment: I don't see here PlayerCharacter class, and what Location class? Is custom class or you are importing it?

Comment: PlayerCharacter and Location are custom interfaces, and are on the back-end side for my game.